# disable an image based on what page are you on

Tags: ruby, ramaze

I have a strange issue which I would like to implement. I've been thinking for some time but I cannot come up with a solution.

So lets say i visited www.rene.com/promotions/hitman .On the RHS of this page I have a side bad showing other promotion images. Now I want to hide the image for hitman from the sidebar. To cut the story short, when I am on a promotion page, the picture on the right sidebar related to the promo I visited wont show. The right hand sidebar uses a loop and loads up all of the images. How I can relate the right hand sidebar with the promotion I visited? The only thing in common is the name of the promo and the folder for the promo images:

promo link: www.rene.com/promotions/hitman

sidebar image: /img/promotions/hitman/250x90.jpg

Comment: Which ruby web framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Find matching data between your current environment and the data in the loop you are iterating. You can find useful information in your `request`. For instance if the image you wish to skip has a `src` or even an `href`, then you can match that against your request environment URL (usually that would be `request.env['PATH_INFO']`) or something similar.

If the `href` of your image/link is the same as the path info in your request, then you should probably skip the current iteration (`next`) since you then would be rendering a link to the page you currently are on.

**Solution 2**

Working with Ramaze, this is how I would solve this problem. First I need to state a few assumptions/claims.

You possibly have a layout template, or an index template to render the two different templates (your page, and the "right hand sidebar") that you need to match between. If your layout or index template renders a partial where you need the match, the solution lies in sending that match as a parameter to that partial.

Your controller (due to your URL it's probably called `promotions.rb`) should (or may) hold an action method called `hitman`. This method represents the action of visiting the page `promotions/hitman`. Declare a variable here that can be used throughout your instance (`instance variable`, [read more here](http://ramaze.net/documentation/file.views.html#Layouts)).

You now have an `instance variable` which you may use in your layout/index template and send as a parameter to the partial.

In the partial, you need to receive it and match it to the object that you are currently iterating over (in your example, the image URL) - if they match you hide that image (or skip the iteration using [next](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) in your loop).